# New field to be shown in crystal report

Tags: crystal-reports, crystal-reports-2008, crystal-reports-xi, crystal-reports-8.5

I have a sql stored procedure which is attached to a crystal report.

The sql sp has 5 fields, i added the 6th new field.

When i click refresh on report field, i don't see the new field.

```
How do i get the added new field to be shown as part of "Database Fields" ?
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Select verify database from the database menu. This should update the schema.

Comment: Thanks, i entered the DB info, then i get - Prompting failed with the following error message 0x8000FFFF.

Comment: Is the report stored locally? Which version of Crystal are you using? Have you got all the latest service packs etc?

Comment: Report is connected to a test server, how do i check which DB the report is connected to, probably my guess is DB path might not be correct.

Comment: set datasource location on the database menu